# Unable to turn off Airplane Mode on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, airplane-mode

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 in my HP Pavilion dv6 notebook, I cannot turn off my Airplane Mode. The toggle button for Airplane Mode in Network option in turned off and it is grayed out.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

Output of `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 06
   serial: 08:2e:5f:7e:6c:e4
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.2.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:26 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff

*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 34
   serial: ac:72:89:da:fa:1b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:31 memory:c4400000-c4401fff
```

Output of `lsmod | grep -e lap -e wmi`:

```
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
snd                    81920  17 
snd                    81920  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
```

Output of `dmesg | grep -i firmware`:

```
[    0.242696] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.309838] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   22.775971] iwlwifi 0000:0d:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The hard block from the 'rfkill list all' output means you actually have a switch to turn on/off the wireless.  Your laptop may have a function key combination or an actual switch to toggle this.

Hope this helps.